# Building a 2-bit adder with a propagation delay of at most 2 gates

Tags: digital-logic, adder, logic-gates

An XOR-gate itself counts as 2 gates, so if I use an XOR-gate the delay would already be 2.

I have no idea how to do this, as a full adder for one bit already contains 2 XOR-gates (or 1 XOR-gate, 1 AND gate and 1 OR gate) so that would already have a delay of 4, while I have to build a 2 bit adder with a delay of at most 2 gates.

Is it actually possible to do this? Otherwise there must be an error in my exercise book.

Comment: Your truth table says?

Comment: Describe the desired full adder by using a truth table, then see if you can synthesize the logic. If you are optimizing for least propagation delay, you may end up replicating some subexpressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with only the standard `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` gates.  For the two-bit adder that takes in two-bit numbers `AB` and `CD`, and outputs a three-bit number `XYZ`, the truth table looks like this:

```
A B C D | X Y Z
0 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 | 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 | 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 | 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 | 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 | 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 | 0 1 1
0 1 1 1 | 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 | 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 | 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 | 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 | 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 | 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 | 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 | 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 | 1 1 0
```

The [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) for `Y` looks like this:

```
CD AB>
V  00 01 11 10
00  0  0  1  1
01  0  1  0  1
11  1  0  1  0
10  1  1  0  0
```

The problem is that since you are only allowed **two** gate delays, and we need both of those: one to `AND` together the bits in each group, and another to then `OR` those groups together.  This means that the groups we can specify are limited to those that do not contain any `NOT`s, i.e. only the following:

```
   A         B          C         D        A*B       A*C       A*D       B*C
. . x x   . x x .    . . . .   . . . .   . . x .   . . . .   . . . .   . . . .
. . x x   . x x .    . . . .   x x x x   . . x .   . . . .   . . x x   . . . .
. . x x   . x x .    x x x x   x x x x   . . x .   . . x x   . . x x   . x x .
. . x x   . x x .    x x x x   . . . .   . . x .   . . x x   . . . .   . x x .

  B*D       C*D       A*B*C     A*B*D     A*C*D     B*C*D    A*B*C*D    True
. . . .   . . . .    . . . .   . . . .   . . . .   . . . .   . . . .   x x x x
. x x .   . . . .    . . . .   . . x .   . . . .   . . . .   . . . .   x x x x
. x x .   x x x x    . . x .   . . x .   . . x x   . x x .   . . x .   x x x x
. . . .   . . . .    . . x .   . . . .   . . . .   . . . .   . . . .   x x x x
```

Note that none of these groups covers the `1001` spot without covering the `1101` spot, which we need for `Y`.  You may be able to get the correct groups using a `NAND`, `NOR`, or `XNOR`; but only if those count as 1 gate delay.

Note that if you are using a technology like CMOS logic where each bit has an inverse available, then using the Karnaugh map technique renders this problem trivial, with an example solution below (where `a` is `NOT A`, etc.):

```
X = AC + ABD + BCD
Y = Acd + abC + Abc + aCd + aBcD + ABCD
Z = bD + Bd
```